# Find the components selected by the user

Tags: install4j

I am trying to implement a form that has several check boxes.
The availability of these is dependent upon the components selected by the use but I cannot find a way of determining which components have been selected.

I would be grateful if someone could give some hints as to how to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Installation components?

context.getInstallationComponentById("the_component_name").isSelected()

will return true/false based on whther that component was selected for install....